# Play Store app suspended due to Hi-res icon

Tags: google-play, icons

I understand that my app can be rejected due to problems with my icon, but suspended? The first time i tryied to create a new app he was rejected by the same reason, and after fixing it the app was aproved. Then 1 week later my app got suspended. Have this already happend to someone here and explain exaclty what is wrong?

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Google doesn't like the icon that you used. Try Contacting the Google Support through the Console. They can explain you what exactly went wrong!